# Basic LINQ expression for an ItemCollection

Tags: .net, linq, itemcollection

I have an [`ItemCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.aspx) that I'd like to query using LINQ. I tried the following (contrived) example:

```
var lItem =
    from item in lListBox.Items
    where String.Compare(item.ToString(), "abc") == true
    select item;
```

Visual Studio keeps telling me `Cannot find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection'. 'Where' not found. Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'item'.`

How do I fix the problem?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

It's because ItemCollection only implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`.

You need to effectively call `Cast<T>()` which is what happens if you specify the type of the range variable explicitly:

```
var lItem = from object item in lListBox.Items
            where String.Compare(item.ToString(), "abc") == 0
            select item;
```

In dot notation, this is:

```
var lItem = lListBox.Items
                    .Cast<object>()
                    .Where(item => String.Compare(item.ToString(), "abc") == 0));
```

If course, if you have a better idea of what's in the collection, you could specify a more restrictive type than `object`.

Comment: Thanks! I also needed to cast the item (from object to its actual type) in the where clause, in order to access the property I was interested in.

Comment: Don't cast in the where clause - just change the type argument to the Cast method!

Comment: I've been chasing this for 30 minutes - my code is cross compiled to Silverlight and WPF - Silverlight worked fine (diff. ItemCollection impl)- WPF needed the cast - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the type of "item"

```
var lItem =
    from object item in lListBox.Items
    where String.Compare(item.ToString(), "abc") == true
    select item;
```