# How do I find items with specific property in an ItemCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, itemcollection

I have an ItemsCollection with UserControls of different types, and need to find if any object satisfies the condition `Any(p => p.GotFocus)`. As the ItemsCollection does not implement IEnumerable, I could cast the collection to a certain type, as explained in [Basic LINQ expression for an ItemCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160854/basic-linq-expression-for-an-itemcollection) like this:

```
bool gotFocus = paragraphsItemControl.Items.Cast<ParagraphUserControl>().Any(p => p.GotFocus);
```

The collection consists of different types of UserControls (each inherits from the same parent though), so an exception is thrown if I cast to a specific type.
How can I query the collection of UserControl objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `OfType()` instead of `Cast()`:

```
bool gotFocus = paragraphsItemControl.Items
     .OfType<ParagraphUserControl>().Any(p => p.GotFocus);
```

But please note that this only controls of type `ParagraphUserControl` will be checked.

Assuming that all of the controls inherited from `Parent` and `Parent` has `GotFocus` property then to check all controls you can do this:

```
bool gotFocus = paragraphsItemControl.Items
     .Cast<Parent>().Any(p => p.GotFocus);
```